# Why can't I assign values to an attribute after creating an instance of class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

I just discovered `attrs` and it's actually great for my upcoming project. While playing around I recognized some behaviour which I can't explain to myself.

I have this piece of code:

```py
from attr import attrs, attrib, Factory

def validate_dict(instance, attribute, value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        raise ValueError(f"Attribute `{attribute.name}` has to be of type dict(), not {type(value)}!")

@attrs(kw_only=True, on_setattr=validate_dict)
class FooBar:
    defaults = attrib(default=Factory(dict), validator=validate_dict)
    config = attrib(default=Factory(dict), validator=validate_dict)
    source = attrib(default=Factory(dict), validator=validate_dict)
    target = attrib(default=Factory(dict), validator=validate_dict)

>>> foobar = FooBar()
>>> foobar
FooBar(defaults={}, config={}, source={}, target={})
>>> foobar.defaults = {'firstname':'Thomas'}
>>> foobar
FooBar(defaults=None, config={}, source={}, target={})
```

Using `foobar.defaults.update(firstname='Thomas')` works, also `foobar = FooBar(defaults={'firstname':'Thomas'})`, but shouldn't work direct assigning as well? Or is the way I use `on_setattr` and `validator` wrong?

When I try to set an attribute with an int, i.e. `foobar.defaults = 1` the ValueError is correctly raised.

Any hints appreciated. Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html) for `on_setattr`:

> If no exception is raised, the attribute is set to the return value of the callable.

Your `validate_dict` returns None, so that is what is being set as the value.  If you want to set the value to the dict passed in, you need to do `return value` in `validate_dict`.  (Presumably the API was set up this way so that such a handler can modify the passed-in value rather than simply accepting or rejecting it.)

Comment: My bad, I'm so stupid. I should read the docs more closely. Thx that solved it. Don't ask me why I missed to return a value. I think I shouldn't do such stuff that late. :)

Comment: Yes that's exactly the reason. This way it's possible to run converters through `on_setattr`. :)